# Linux command to extract single file from tar as bytes / byte array

Tags: linux, byte, tar

I want to extract a single file from tar file as bytes.

I'm aware of the command "tar -xf xyz.tar abc.pdf"

This extracts a physical file in the current location. But i want to extract directly as bytes or byte array.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want to achieve - do you want a command that takes a tar archive and a filename as input and writes a stream of bytes to STDOUT? Or do you want an API / library that is able to read tar archives?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt im executing the above command from .net application, in return i want the bytes of the extracted file which i will flush on to the browser.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Add `O` option:

```
    tar xOf xyz.tar abc.pdf
```

`man tar` says:

```
 -O, --to-stdout
       extract files to standard output
```